# Problem with Android SDK on Linux with Eclipse Helios

Tags: android, eclipse

I just installed the Android SDK on my machine.  I am running Fedora 13 (64 bit) and the Android kit is r06 for Linux.  I am running Eclipse Helios.  I get this error when I try to link to the sdk inside Eclipse:

[2010-07-21 07:10:23 - adb]Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "/home/jmneedham/android-sdk-linux/tools/adb": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

I have checked directory permissions and those seem to be fine, but I am not sure if the SDK is just not compatible with 64 bit Linux or what to do to fix this.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when *you* run adb? Maybe there's a permissions problem with the programs in the tools directory, rather than the directory itself.

Comment: get a message about bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory (though it does exist) looks like a problem of the SDK being 32 bit and my Linux being 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

I found on another forum that this might be caused by some library not present in your jdk. Their issue was solved by downloading :

lib32-libstdc++5
lib32-libx11
lib32-ncurses
lib32-zlib
lib32-sdl
lib32-libxext

If you want more details or if these libraries does not help, check [the whole topic here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=66878)

Comment: These appear to be 32 bit libraries, I am on a 64 bit Linux (specifically Fedora 13).  Maybe if I try lib64 instead?

Comment: Android SDK's tools such as adb requires you to install 32bit libraries on 64bit systems since they have been linked this way (only a "Linux (i386)" package is available for download from Google).

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with the SDK being 32 bit and my system being 64 bit.  I am going to wait for the folks at Android to develop a 64 bit version before I decide to do anything with the kit.

Thanks for any help on this.  Hope that the people that develop the SDK note that a lot of us may hold out for a 64 bit version.  I of course, don't need it for professional reasons at this time, but I was interested.  Just not interested in 32 bit computing any longer :-).

Answer (score 0):

Mike Needham said:

> Hope that the people that develop the SDK note that a lot of us may hold out for a 64 bit version. I of course, don't need it for professional reasons at this time, but I was interested. Just not interested in 32 bit computing any longer :-).

You do realize that the Android targets are all 32 bit, right? Even the nvidia tegra dual core CPU is 32bit. It's the most advanced of CPUs in current Android device, afaik.

If you hold out for 64 bit, you'll miss most of what's going on in Android development for a number of years.