# Problem with Android SDK on Fedora 14 with Eclipse

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, fedora

I just installed the Android SDK on my machine. I am running Fedora 14 (64 bit) and the Android kit is r07 for Linux. I am running Eclipse Indigo. I get an error when I try to link to the sdk inside Eclipse, saying :
    Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "/home/naman/workspace/android-sdk-linux/tools/adb": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

The problem is also documented here
[Problem with Android SDK on Linux with Eclipse Helios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299078/problem-with-android-sdk-on-linux-with-eclipse-helios?answertab=active#tab-top)

But with no solutions.

 A solution is there for Ubuntu machines--
[Android SDK on a 64-bit linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710499/android-sdk-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine)

Can someone suggest a similar solution maybe for fedora??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked like magic 
http://beginlinux.com/blog/2009/09/installing-32-bit-support-into-64-bit-fedora-11/

though installing all i686 libs as in 
http://beginlinux.com/blog/2009/09/installing-32-bit-support-into-64-bit-fedora-11/comment-page-1/#comment-1514  didn't work.

Comment: Hi, ghostCoder - you're absolutely correct. You won't be able to get anything to work on a 64-bit platform unless you install the necessary 32-bit support in your links.  However, the "errno=2" (file not found) was because they moved "adb:.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem until I figured out that they have moved adb (and then I had updated it automatically).

See if you can see it here (or make Eclipse try here): `/home/naman/workspace/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb`

Also see if you have the file: `/home/naman/workspace/android-sdk-linux/tools/adb_has_moved.txt`

Answer (score 1):

For Fedora-16  64-bit I solved this as follows:

```sh
yum install glibc.i686 glibc-devel.i686
yum install ncurses-libs.i686
yum install libstdc++.i686
```

After installing, restart Eclipse and Android packages should load.