# Android: ADB is somehow not working (on Fedora 16)

Tags: android, adb, fedora

I'm running Fedora 16 x64 with xfce desktop. Installation of Android Developer Tools (adt plugin) was successfull from Eclipse. I can even run an Emulator. It's just that adb command is not working from the Linux command line. Even if I cd to the platform-tools folder and run adb devices I get this output:

```
bash: adb: command not found
```

Eclipse also reports an error about this. By the way adb file is marked as executable. Any help would be great...

Comment: What is the output of `./adb version`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem was already addressed here:

[Problem with Android SDK on Fedora 14 with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606846/problem-with-android-sdk-on-fedora-14-with-eclipse)

and here

[Android SDK on a 64-bit linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710499/android-sdk-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine)

Please let me know.

adb is located under folder platform-tools and in order to run it you have 2 options.

Option 1: Add the SDK/platform-tools folder into your shell PATH (BASH I guess)

Option 2: go under the platform-tools folder and run it using: ./adb

for instance ./adb logcat

Cheers

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to describe. The output of ./adb logcat is:
./adb: symbol lookup error: /lib/libncurses.so.5: undefined symbol: curscr

Comment: wow, it looks to me like if you have installed a 32 bit version of the SDK on a 64 bit version of linux and adb cannot link your system libraries. Quite common problem, you can install it but linking has problems. (the other situation as 64 bit SDK on a 32 bit linux looks impossible).

Comment: Yeah but there's only one linux pack to download: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html ... so is it possible to get 64 version of SDK for Linux, because I don't see it there...

Comment: wops, my bad. Can you please report the following command on your shell? 

    uname -a

Comment: Linux LaptopGreco 3.1.6-1.fc16.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 21 22:41:17 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: mumble, another output I would like to ask you is:

/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libncurses

Comment: libncursesw.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libncursesw.so.5
 libncursesw.so.5 (libc6) => /lib/libncursesw.so.5
 libncurses.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libncurses.so.5
 libncurses.so.5 (libc6) => /lib/libncurses.so.5

Comment: I'm still pulling my teeth because of this. I tried this: http://beginlinux.com/blog/2009/09/installing-32-bit-support-into-64-bit-fedora-11/ ... but of course does not work for me... Not even one package gets installed so must be something with fedora repositories...

Comment: have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710499/android-sdk-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine

Comment: Yes but ia32-libs were already installed. I still get this error when running the adb command:          ./adb: symbol lookup error: /lib/libncurses.so.5: undefined symbol: curscr       ................   and building SDK yourself... I don't imagine how that would be...

Comment: unbelievable, let's solve the issue together :)

try to report the output of the JAVA and JAVAC versions.

please run the following:

java -version
javac -version

Comment: java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.4) (fedora-61.1.10.4.fc16-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo yum install android-tools -y`

Comment: i have no idea.. that was a long time ago. i've never used fedora since :)